# duplicate div then do a horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to clone `#main` then put my ajax result there (hidden), after doing so I will make it scroll horizontally to the left hiding the current one then display the clone.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="main">
        <p>Click here to start</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#main{
    width:460px;
    min-height:200px;
    background:#3F9FD9;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.container {
    position:relative;
}
```

​

Javascript:

```
$('#main').click(function(){
    //clone.html(data)
    var clone = $(this).clone().html('<p>Ajax loaded content</p>').css(
            {position:'absolute',right:'0','margin-right':'-460px',top:0}
        ).attr('class','love').insertAfter($(this));
    $(this).css({position:'relative'});
        var width = $(window).width()-$(this).outerWidth()/2;
    $('#main').animate({'left':'-'+width},4000);
});
```

but i'm stuck on the idea on *how to make both `#main` animate to the left and position the second div at the center*?

---

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gjbQ/1/)

**EDIT:** Now i'm only stuck on how to animate the clone.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of took a different approach to your question, is this kind of what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/3s7Fw/5/show

I thought, rather than do some animating ourselves, why not let jQuery's hide function do it for us? This could definitely be made to work better, but it communicates the thought.

**JavaScript**

```
$('.container').on('click', '.loaded-content', function(){
    $this = $(this);

    //clone.html(data)
    var clone = $this.clone().html('<p>Ajax loaded content</p>').attr("id", '');

    $this.after(clone);
    $this.hide('slow');
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="main" class="loaded-content">
        <p>Click here to start</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#main, .loaded-content{
    width:460px;
    min-height:200px;
    background:#3F9FD9;
    margin:0 auto;
    float: left;
}
.container {
    position:relative;
    width: 920px;
}
```

​If this is not the desired functionality, then you might be interested in a slider. There are a number of good slider plugins already out there that you can use. The difficult part would probably be adding a `addNewSlide` function to your chosen slider, assuming it didn't already have one.

Comment: looks very nice, but if I remove the float (since it's centered) the clone goes down the div.